# how to access popup button from main file in kivy and change its text according to situation

Tags: python, kivy

in my login system I want to create a popup box that will be displayed when there is an error in the username, password, or verification password. Can someone help me in how to make the popup show with different labels everytime an error happens

here is the code for main file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    def signIn(self):
        pass

    def signUp(self):
        # db=open('QuizData.txt','r')
        username=self.ids.uname.text
        password=self.ids.passw.text
        repassword=self.ids.repassw.text
        if password!=repassword:
           pass      #i want a popup box to appear if this is true
    
    def popup(self):
                pass
class QuizWindow(Screen):
    pass

class QuizScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('loginLayoutCSS.kv')

class Login(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__=='__main__':
    Login().run()
```

here is the code for .kv file

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
#:import utils kivy.utils
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyPopup@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: True
    size_hint:0.6,0.3
    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5}
    title: 'Error'
    Button:
        text:'close'
        fonr_size: 20
        on_release: root.dismiss()
<MyTextInput@TextInput>
    font_size:25
    # size_
    background_normal:''
    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#8c8c8c')

QuizScreenManager:
    LoginWindow:
    QuizWindow:

<LoginWindow>:
    name:'login'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size: root.width,root.height
        spacing: 20
        padding: 20

        Label:
            id:heading
            text:'Welcome back, sign in'
            font_size:32

        MyTextInput:
            id:uname
            text:'username'

        MyTextInput:
            id:passw
            text:'password'

        MyTextInput:
            id:repassw
            text:'re-enter Password'
            multiline:False
            size_hint_y: None
            height:0
            opacity:0

        Button:
            text:'Sign In'
            id:signin
            size_hint_y:0.6
            on_release: 
                app.root.current='quizwindow'
                root.manager.transition.direction='up'

        Button:
            text:'New here? Sign up Now! click here'
            id:signup
            on_press:
                # signin.size_hint_y = None
                repassw.size_hint_y = 0.6
                repassw.opacity = 1
                repassw.background_color = utils.get_color_from_hex('#8c8c8c')
                root.signUp()
                root.popup()
                signup.text = 'Sign Up'
                signin.opacity = 0
                

<QuizWindow>:
    name:'quizwindow'

    Button:
        text:'go back'
        on_release: 
            app.root.current='login'
            root.manager.transition.direction='down'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `id` to the `MyPopup` class to allow you to access a `Label` that can contain your message. Here is a modified version of that portion of your `kv` file:

```
<MyPopup@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: True
    size_hint:0.6,0.3
    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5}
    title: 'Error'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: message
        Button:
            text:'close'
            fonr_size: 20
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Then you can access that `Label` in your python code like this:

```
def signUp(self):
    # db=open('QuizData.txt','r')
    username = self.ids.uname.text
    password = self.ids.passw.text
    repassword = self.ids.repassw.text
    if password != repassword:
        popup = Factory.MyPopup()
        popup.ids.message.text = 'passwords do not match'
        popup.open()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I think it will work fine now